# What's the difference between FETCH and FETCH BULK?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm learning in practice about packages and this is a difference that I noticed between two very similar packages.

What is the functional difference between these two lines?

```
FETCH key INTO id, source, file;

FETCH BULK key COLLECT INTO id, source, file;
```

edit:
Also, when I try to compile the package using the second line I get the following error:

- Erro(259,49): PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list

Answer (score 0):

FETCH retrieves the next row from a cursor's result set into one or more scalar variables. FETCH BULK retrieves all rows (up to the optional LIMIT) into one or more collections. See [Fetch documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fetch_statement.htm#LNPLS01320). Your compile error ( PLS-00497:...) is that you have attempted to fetch all rows into a list of scalar variables. Except your syntax is incorrect, should be `FETCH column_list BULK COLLECT INTO collection_name(s)`

For bulk collecting:

```
declare  
    type key_list is table of some_table.key%type; 
    key_array  key_list; 
    cursor c_keys is 
           (select keys from some_table); begin
      
begin
    open c_keys; 
    fetch c_keys 
     bulk collect 
     into key_array;
    close c_keys; 

    -- process each of the keys in the key_list array
    for index_var in 1 .. key_array.count
    loop
        --process key_array(index_var) ;  Lets just "print it" 
        dbms_output.put_line( 'Key(' || index_var || ' is ' ||key_array(index_var));   
    end loop; 
end ;
```

Comment: If the above resolved your issue then kindly accept it; if not then what is the remaining issue. This helps future questioners having the same issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.